# Change environment variable for Mac 10.7

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion, environment-variables

I would like to set the PATH on my Mac 10.7.

So in `/etc/launchd.conf` I wrote:

```
setenv PATH /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin/:/usr/local/sbin/
```

**and I restarted Mac.**

However when I write in terminal

```
echo $PATH
```

I get:

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/bin/:/usr/local/sbin/
```

How can I change the PATH param?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/my/stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

Reset `launchd.conf` to its default settings. It's better to keep `/etc` files alone if you don't know what you are doing. :-)

Also, it's not advisable to completely overwrite your PATH; you can add directories to your pre-existing PATH in a very simple way.

You can change OS X's PATH parameter in the shell environment simply by editing `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`. For example, in my `.profile` I have added some directories to my pre-existing PATH:

```
PATH="${PATH}:~/bin:/Users/Shared/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin"
```

You have some subdirectories of `/opt` in your PATH. I guess that they have been added by [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/). If you want to remove them, simply comment out (#) or remove the corresponding lines in your `.profile`. To edit those hidden files, you can use CLI editors like vim or nano (included into OS X).